# How to set connect server (node) to work on HTTPS? Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: node.js, npm, node.js-connect

I am using [connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) server, and I need to create my localhost under https (even if certificates are not valid).

At the moment I am using the following script which createa a server listing at http://127.0.0.1:8080/

I need to set it up as: https://127.0.0.1:8080/

How to configure connect server?

```
gulp.task('dev:connect', function () {
    // runs connect server for rapid development
    connect.server({
        root: ''
    });
});
```

I am also trying this but with not success:

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('b.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('a.crt')
};
var app = connect(); // error here object is not a function
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Are you using var https = require('https');

Comment: @irimawi yes I am using var https = require('https');

Comment: Do you have a web server reverse proxying port 3000 to 8080? If not, you are creating your server on port 3000

Comment: @irimawi thanks for your comment, I change port to 8080 and now I get this error: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Comment: Are you on windows? Do you see ^M at the end of every line in your certificate?

Comment: I am on window and I do not see the  ^M at the end of every line. File is also saved as UTF-8. Thanks for your time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the following, I think the key is protected:

```
  $ openssl rsa -in b.key -out b-unprotected.key
  $ cat b-unprotected.key a.crt > a.pem
```

Let me know if this works